# Figuring out all possible combinations for a given circumstance

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

I am not sure if this is the correct approach to these questions.

Question 3: A bag of lego containing 10 red pieces and 5 blue pieces. 
If you reach into the bag and pull 3 pieces

a.) How many ways have can I have all red pieces

Solution: So you have to think how many ways can I pick 3 pieces out of 15
and then how many ways can I pick all red pieces out of the 10 available.

${10\choose3} \cdot {15\choose3} $

b.) How many ways contain only 1 red piece?

Solution: So you have to think how many ways can I pick 2 blue pieces out of 15
and then how many ways can I pick 1 red piece out of the 15 available.

${10\choose1} \cdot {15\choose1} + {5\choose2} \cdot {14\choose2}$

c.) How many ways contain at least 2 or more red pieces?

Solution: So you have to think how many ways can I pick at least 2 pieces out of 15
and then how many ways can I pick at least 1 of the pieces available.

${10\choose2} \cdot {15\choose2} + {5\choose1} \cdot {13\choose1}$

Comment: There are only $\binom {15}3$ ways in total to choose $3$ pieces, so how could there be more ways to choose if you add a restriction?

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So instead of adding I should be subtracting?

Comment: I'm just looking at the first question.  There's no adding or subtracting and the $\binom {15}3$ doesn't appear to have anything to do with it.

Comment: The second question is ambiguous.  Do you mean "exactly one red piece" or "at least one red piece"?  And the third question makes no sense at all.

Comment: In the second part you need to choose 1 red piece from the 10 red, $\binom{10}{1}$ and then the other 2 from the 5 blue, $\binom{5}{2}$. Then the answer is $\binom{10{1}\binom{5}{2}$.

Comment: Modified the questions, I'm sorry my apologies.

Comment: Also, $\binom {10}3$ is nowhere near $3003$.  I think you should start over.

Comment: It seems to me a.) is correct. b.) ${10\choose1} * {5\choose2}$ c.) ${10\choose2} * {5\choose1}$

Comment: a.) ${10\choose3}$

Answer (score 1):

a.) ${10\choose3}$ 
Of the 10 available red balls you want to know how many ways you can pick 3, regardless of order

b.) ${10\choose1}{5\choose2}$
Of the 10 red balls you want to choose 1 and of the 5 blue balls you want 2

c.) ${10\choose2}{5\choose1} + {10\choose3}{5\choose0}$
Of the 10 red balls you want to choose 2 and of the 5 blue balls you want 1

Comment: Your first two answers are correct.  The third question asks for the number of ways of selecting two *or more* red pieces.  You found the number of ways of selecting exactly two.

Comment: Right, so the correction being: ${10\choose2}{5\choose1} + {10\choose3}{5\choose0}$?

Comment: That is correct.